# Como puedo encontrar un numero en un string en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un campo en una tabla llamado personal y los datos que guarda es un string de numeros delimitados por comas, ej:

```
10,32,43,55,2,45
```

Al momento de querer hacer una consulta para buscar un empleado en especifico quiero utilizar esta función:

```
    foreach ($ids as $id):
            $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM projectP WHERE personal LIKE '%$id%'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
            var_dump($row);
    endforeach;
```

Pero si el empleado es el 44 y en el string hay un 4 solamente, tmb lo encuentra y necesito que nomas encuentre los que son 44, alguna idea?

Comment: No es recomendable guardar listas separadas por comas en la base de datos.  Pero si no puedes o es muy dificil separarlos, intenta con `LIKE '%$id,%'`.  Nota que esto no te funcionara si el unico valor en la columna es `4` o si es el ultimo valor en la lista.

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable guardar listas separadas por comas en la base de datos. Pero si no puedes o es muy dificil separarlos, puedes lograrlo agregando mas logica y usando `explode` asi:

```
foreach ($ids as $id):
        $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id FROM projectP WHERE personal LIKE '%$id%'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $valores = explode(',', $row['id']);
        if (in_array($id, $valores) {
            var_dump($row);
        }
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

puede intentar validando el string que se te pasa:

```
function val_number($str){
      if(preg_match('^-?\d+(?:,\d+)?$',$str)){
          return true;
      }
    return false;
}

$n1 = "239,12312,12312";
$n2 = "239,12312,12312,";
$n3 = "as239,12312,12312.";
$n4 = ",239,12312,12312";

val_number($n1);   //true
val_number($n2);   //false
val_number($n3);   //false
val_number($n4);   //false
```

luego de tu consulta utilizas

```
$ids = explode(',', $row['id']);
foreach($ids as $r){
 echo $r == $id ? "son iguales" : "no son iguales";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar `IN` en tu consulta **sql**, que se encarga de buscar registros cuando tu campo `personal` este entre los valores proporcionados:

```
SELECT id FROM projectP WHERE personal IN ($id)
```